# bash - correct logic for a flag arguments options statement

Tags: bash, shell

I have two scenarios for what is correct for the script otherwise needs to be flagged as bad usage. Would would be correct logic for the options (flags or arguments, not really sure what there reference as)?  Does it matter if I put the function before or after main code?

EDIT question:  My logic doesn't catch when I make a call with no variables?  It actually tries to execute and no usage displays.  Second question if I put in a file for the input but it doesn't exist, it still tries to execute?  How do deal with these situations?

./example.sh -i input.file

./example.sh -i input.file -o output.file

```
usage()
{
cat << EOF
usage: $0 options

This script run with two types of formats.
./example.sh -i input.file
Note: In this above case, a predesignated name will give for output files.
./example.sh -i input.file -o output.file


OPTIONS:
   -h      Show this message
   -i      Input file - ./example.sh -i input.file
   -o      Outpute file - .example.sh -i input.file -o output.file
EOF
}

INPUTFILE=
OUTPUTFILE=

while getopts “i:io:h:?” OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
         i)
             INPUTFILE=$OPTARG
             ;;
         o)
             OUTPUTFILE=$OPTARG
             ;;
         h)
             usage
             exit 1
             ;;
         ?)
             usage
             exit
             ;;
     esac
done
```

jm666 proposed answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

#define your options here
OPT_STR="h:i:o:c"

do_work() {
   #your main work-code here
}

#common functions
err() { 1>&2 echo "$0: Error: $@"; return 1; }
required_arg() { err "Option -$1 need argument"; }
checkarg() { [[ "$1" =~ ${optre:--} ]] && { required_arg "$2"; return 1; } || { echo "$1" ; return 0; } }
phelp() { err "Usage: $0" "$(sed 's/^://;s/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\)/ -&/g;s/:/ [arg] /g;s/  */ /g' <<< "$OPT_STR")"; return 1; }

## MAIN
declare -A OPTION
optre=$(sed 's/://g;s/.*/-[&]/' <<<"$OPT_STR")
while getopts "$OPT_STR" opt;
do
    #change here a,b,c to your options
    case $opt in
    i) OPTION[$opt]=$(checkarg "$OPTARG" $opt)  || exit 1;;
    o) OPTION[$opt]=$(checkarg "$OPTARG" $opt)  || exit 1;;
    c) OPTION[$opt]=1;;
    h) phelp || exit 1;;
    :) required_arg "$OPTARG" || exit 1 ;;
    \?) err "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" || exit 1;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
echo "iarg: ${OPTION[i]:-undefined}"
echo "oarg: ${OPTION[o]:-undefined}"
echo "carg: ${OPTION[c]:-0}"
echo "remainder args: =$@="

for arg in "$@"
do
    do_work "$arg"
done
```

Proposed modification of jm666

Having problems trying to understand where to add variable assignment from the original code like INPUTFILE and OUTPUTFILE ???

Comment: Put the function before the main code.

Comment: Does that include Global variables but of course not "#!/bin/bash"?

Comment: It includes function declaration, e.g. `usage()` in your case.

Comment: You need to define the function before you use it; otherwise, the script will look for a command instead of the function. The shell doesn't necessarily parse the entire script before executing the code. You shouldn't repeat `i` in the option letters.  That is, `i:io:h:` should be just `i:o:h:` — or, better, `h:i:o:` in alphabetic order.  It won't hurt (`getopts` won't notice the repeat) but it is a little careless.

Comment: You need more tests, if you want handle bad invocations like `./example.sh -i -o file` In this case the `INPUTFILE` get assigned `-o`...

Comment: @jm666: that is the way that the `getopt()` function works, and the way the `getopts` command works.  There isn't a simple way to avoid that, short of writing your own analogue to `getopts`, which isn't doable because it performs built-in magic (assigning to a variable), so you have to do what GNU `getopt` does instead.

Comment: I updated my posting for another question.  jm666 brings up a good point with ./example.sh -i -o file?  How can i deal that as well? It might be same way as I should handle not finding the file?

Comment: @Jonathan  The use case of just the output file is not correct. I can't do anything with that and I want to not allow that situation. Thats why I put "io".  Is there way to catch that situation of when the user puts just "o"?

Comment: Ususaly the correct flow is: 1) - handle all supplied args, 2) check the the "logic" - e.g. mandatory args and combinations...

Comment: Yes: after the loop, check that if `$OUTPUTFILE` is set then `$INFPUTFILE` is also set.  There isn't another way to enforce the requirement that I know of.  Similarly with mutually exclusive options; you parse the options and then enforce mutual exclusivity.  You can do that in the body of the loop — when a mutually exclusive option is detected, see whether one of the other options in the mutually exclusive group has already been set — but you can also do it after the loop.

Comment: @jm666 Thank you for your effort jm666!

Answer (score 0):

I just ended keeping my code and writing a function that checks if the FILEINPUT exist which assures me that if you input a file at all or not with -o, then it will catch it.

```
INPUTFILE= 
OUTPUTFILE=

while getopts i:o:h OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
         i)
             INPUTFILE=$OPTARG
             ;;
     o)
         OUTPUTFILE=$OPTARG
             ;;
         h)
             usage
         exit 1
             ;;
         ?)
             usage
             exit
             ;;
     esac
done


if [ ! -f $INPUTFILE ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
    usage
    exit
fi
```